# Trouble outputting Float value using Jackson library for Java

Tags: java, json, floating-point, jackson

When using Jackson to convert a pojo to a string I am finding that my Float values are being truncated  5852402.63111111 is becoming 5852402.6 when I print out the string.  Also some of the values come with E7 or some number after them when they cannot be put into a value with 8 digits.  Is there something that must be done with the printer or mapper to set it to not truncate my values.  I have been looking through the documentation and have had no luck figuring this one out.  Thanks!

Currently my method for converting to a string is:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    DefaultPrettyPrinter printer = new DefaultPrettyPrinter();
    mapper.writer(printer).writeValueAsString(myObject);
```

Comment: How much precision are you expecting for a `float` value? (Hint: if you're relying on more than 7, that's probably a bad idea...)

Comment: Not all real values can fit into a 32-bit float. Especially such a large one. Just do `System.out.println(5852402.63111111F);` and you'll see that Jackson has nothing to do with the truncation. Use double.

Comment: Switched it to Double, now everything works, Thanks!